# Show $(a_1+···+a_n)^2 ≤ n(a^2_1+···+a^2_n).$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Show that if $n ∈ \mathbb{N}$ and $a_1,...,a_n$ are nonnegative real numbers, then  $(a_1+···+a_n)^2 ≤ n(a^2_1+···+a^2_n).$

What I have tried:

Set $t = a_1+ ...+ a_{n-1}$

Then square the LHS as so
$$(t+a_n)^2 =t^2+2ta_n+a^2_n$$
$$=t^2+ta_n+ta_n+a^2_n$$
$$=t(t+a_n)+a_n(t+a_n)$$
$$=(t+a_n)(t+a_n)$$
$$\implies (t+a_n)(t+a_n) \le n(t^2+a_n^2)$$
$$\implies(t+a_n)\le n(t+a_n)$$

Which would imply that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the equality holds. Does my proof work?

Comment: I don't get your line of reasoning? How from $(t+a_n)^2 = (t+a_n)(t+a_n)$ (which by the way is easier to establish) you get $(t+a_n)(t+a_n) \le n(t^2+a_n^2)$? But your problem can be easily proved by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Let me follow up on Dominik's comment: Let $a=(a_1,\ldots,a_n), b=(1,\ldots,1)\in\Bbb R^n.$ Then $|\langle a,b\rangle^2\le\|b\|^2\|a\|^2.$ I don't think you have proven anything. Do you want to prove it by induction?

Comment: You can also use the convexity of the function $f(x)=x^2$ and apply Jensen.

Comment: Since $a_1,\ldots,a_n\ge 0,$ you can use the [**QM-AM** inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities).

Comment: @Invisible Is that inequality named the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? Seems like that's exactly what I need. Thanks

Comment: No, this does not work at all. The consequent of the first implication is the thesis, and does not follow from the trivial $(t+a_n)^2=(t+a_n)(t+a_n)$.

Comment: @me.limes, you should study systematically. This question belongs to either linear algebra or algebra-precalculus and, seeing your questions, you even do ODE's and probability. First learn the theory step by step and then search the site. (=:

Comment: Divide both sides by $n^2$. Then you see that $\bar{a}^2\leq\bar{a^2}$. Since the squaring operation is a convex function, we see that the inequality is true (by Jensen's inequality).

Answer (score 1):

Want to show that
$(\sum_{k=1}^n a_k)^2
\le n\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^2
$
or
$s_1(n)^2
\le n s_2(n)
$
where
$s_m(n)
=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^m
$.

True for $n=1$
(trivial) and
$n=2$ (easy).

If true for $n$, then

$\begin{array}\\
s_1^2(n+1)
&=(s_1(n)+a_{n+1})^2\\
&=s_1^2(n)+2a_{n+1}s_1(n)+a_{n+1}^2\\
&\le ns_2(n)+2a_{n+1}\sqrt{n s_2(n)}+a_{n+1}^2\\
\end{array}
$

so we want

$\begin{array}\\
ns_2(n)+2a_{n+1}\sqrt{n s_2(n)}+a_{n+1}^2
&\le (n+1)s_2(n+1)\\
&= (n+1)(s_2(n)+a_{n+1}^2)\\
&= (n+1)s_2(n)+(n+1)a_{n+1}^2\\
\end{array}
$

or
$2a_{n+1}\sqrt{n s_2(n)}
\le s_2(n)+na_{n+1}^2
$

or

$\begin{array}\\
0
&\le na_{n+1}^2-2a_{n+1}\sqrt{n s_2(n)}+s_2(n)\\
&=n\left(a_{n+1}^2-2a_{n+1}\sqrt{ \dfrac{s_2(n)}{n}}+\dfrac{s_2(n)}{n}\right)\\
&=n\left(a_{n+1}-\sqrt{ \dfrac{s_2(n)}{n}}\right)^2\\
\end{array}
$

which is true
with equality iff
$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{ \dfrac{s_2(n)}{n}}
$.

Comment: Ridiculously long proof for something that follows immediately from AM-GM inequality or C-S inequality.

Comment: I wanted to see if I could come up with a proof by induction that does not use any other results. I was pleased that I succeeded.